# Which is best firebase or php and json with mysql for android app?

Tags: android, mysql, firebase

I am confused in between Firebase and etc websites that provides backend services and in using php and mysql with a hosting for my android app. What should i choose and why will you please suggest me.
I have searched many times on  google and youtube but still didn't get any proper answer.

Comment: It will depend on how much money you can afford to spend. If you are poor and you are just starting up a home setup is perfectly fine using the free NO-IP with a LAMP server setup on a home PC running linux server. If you have money you can use a remote server service that you can tailor to your needs -- eg -- https://www.exascale.co.uk/dedicated-servers  -- another Option is to host your Server in a datacenter but that will cost a bit of cash

Comment: I can spend $4-$5 /month

Comment: @Tasos While I'm a big fan of inexpensive VPS services, these are not trivial to get running properly and it takes some dedication to *keep* them running. A packaged solution like Firebase is certainly worth evaluating.

Comment: Cool you can afford $1 more than me. Well a Home Setup for you to begin with is perfectly fine. A minimum of 20 to 50 Megabits Internet connection speed is a must though

Comment: @ tadman -- i dont believe that. If you are poor why pay anyone to do the Job for you. You should learn to manage what you have yourself and save your money. Its not hard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it depends on your needs,
**Choose Firebase**

- If you need to use real-time database eg. online chatting app
- if have not worked on server side programming languages before
- Want to build the backend part of the app in shorter time. Firebase simplifies the development process
- Free if you have users less in ten thousands of users (assuming you don't use intensive data storage)

**Choose PHP/MySQL when**

- If you like the concept of relational database
- If you are familiar with a server-side programming language
- If you like to use SQL queries
- Will be cheap if you have more than hundreds of thousands of users or you use intensive data storage.

Generally if your project is used by many users firebase is expensive(eg. above 10,000 monthly active users), but for a simple project it is easy to setup, saves you server cost.

Comment: I m now trying to learn+make android app! I have searched and came to a conclusion that firebase could be bad for me (even if its simple). I started to build it with PHP and MySQL (json) (i have experience with them). The only question is what are the security risk of using PHP/MySQL (i know about SQL injections)?

Comment: Is this still a valid consideration in 2023? I planned to use PHP/MariaDB for REST API when my app will need to "phone home" then I read an article suggesting to use firebase for small projects. I don't want to be locked in but yet I don't know much about load balancing and server stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to keep in mind that there's usually two concerns here: A *local* database kept on the device and a *server* database that the device interfaces with over an API.

The local database should be something quick, simple, and efficient. Perhaps Firebase is a good fit for your project, but [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) is also very popular.

The server database is typically something  more robust, with emphasis on data integrity, scalability under heavy load, and features that make managing larger amounts of data more practical. MySQL is one example of this, but [Postgres](http://postgresql.org) and [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org) are also very popular.

It's important to remember that your mobile application *will* need to interface with the database over an API which is where a language like PHP comes in handy. [JSON](http://json.org) is a very popular format with a light-weight syntax and support in pretty much every language and makes a good transport encoding for arbitrary data. A JSON-based API is very quick to implement and yet will serve you very well in the long-run, enough that most mobile apps use some form of this for communication.

Interfacing directly with a centralized server database such as MySQL from your Android app is a terrible idea and will lead to endless trouble: The MySQL security layer isn't capable of making fine-grained distinctions between various types of access. A proper API gives you complete control over what can and can't be done through your service and what can be read from or written to the database.

Comment: So what you will recommend firebase or hostgator for hosting and mysql database and php for connecting them?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend shared hosting for anything, but if that's what you're stuck with you can make do. If you're evaluating Firebase and it fits your needs, give it a shot, but keep in mind that being stuck on a platform like that can be trouble. Make sure you have a plan B in case that doesn't work out. Given a choice between Hostgator and Firebase, I'd pick Firebase every time.

Comment: Can you give me advantages and disadvantages of firebase over shared hosting service provider like godday and hostgator?

Comment: GoDaddy and Hostgator are the worst possible options for hosting your application. Firebase is better by default, it's not even a contest. Better solutions do require you to know how to set-up and administer a small, inexpensive server.

Comment: And please tell me what if i want my website and app interconnected?

Comment: I think you're mistaking me for a paid consultant.

Comment: @tadman For a long time I was wondering why couldn't I just use a database in my app without sticking to APIs, but I couldn't find an answer, or rather, I didn't know how to ask this question. Your great answer gave me some answers but not all answers, you only mentioned `The MySQL security layer isn't capable of making fine-grained distinctions between various types of access` , but can you give more details why this is a bad idea?

Comment: @AhmedSuror You can implement a very complex ACL in your application layer, regardless of the language used. You can restrict access to fields based on user role, perform validation on data, rate limit, and more. MySQL affords none of that, it's just a dumb data store with very broad access control restrictions (database, table in general) and is **not** intended to be exposed directly to arbitrary end-users who can poke, probe, and easily DDOS it.

Comment: @AhmedSuror It's very common for an app to have complex rules like "You can only change your account name if your account is verified, hasn't been renamed in the last 24 hours, and your account is not suspended, plus the new name must be between 2 and 24 letters, and cannot contain any of the words in the block list, plus is limited to no more than 2 emoji." You could do that in a database trigger if you want to go "full DBA", but it's exponentially harder than just doing it in application code.

Comment: @AhmedSuror The tools for hardening an HTTP application's exposed services are vastly better and more mature than those for protecting MySQL from malicious access, as it's not intended to be exposed in the first place. You have hundreds of tools to turn to in the HTTP space. You have few for MySQL. My advice: Strictly firewall it, never, ever let random people poke and probe it.

Comment: @tadman Really thanks for the clarification, I hope you edit your answer and include these comments.